# Graphics flicker when using repaint() method

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a JFrame in which I have used .setContentPane to invoke a JPanel because I want to keep the main JFrame's menu bar on top of each panel I invoke.  I have used the following to open up the JPanel:

```
 private void jMenuItem_caseOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    caseNewPanel = new CaseNewPanel();
    this.setContentPane(caseNewPanel);
    this.setTitle("Case Menu");
    this.setSize(1183,908);
    this.setBounds(5, 5, 1183, 908);
    this.invalidate(); this.validate();
    this.repaint();      
}
```

The graphics flicker when I invoke the jPanel, but when I go back to the main frame, the graphics do not flicker.  I do not know if I should use cardlayout because I want the main menu of the main frame to appear on each panel.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Why does the main menu need to appear on each panel?  Why not just let it appear where it's suppose to (and where the user expects it)?  Also, you'll get a better response if you can provide a runnable demonstration of your issue

Comment: Pardon my confusion about your question, but what do you mean by "why not just let it appear where it is suppose to?"  Whenever I open up a panel from the main menu (menu item) I want the main menu to remain from the main frame, so I don't remove the main frame, just use this.setcontentpane to a new panel, but is that a poor way of doing this?

Comment: My code is rather large to place here, because I have several classes of panels.....I will see what I can post better in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you have main frame?  Most (windows) apps have a main menu bar that appears under the title and above the content, why do all your panels need to have their own (which, based on your question), seems to the same thing

Comment: I made my own menu bar with menu items.  It is not the standard menu bar with File, Edit, etc.  I have a custom menu bar.

Comment: So?  It's a menu bar with menu items?  Users will still expected to see the menu in a standardised location. Also, you might like to have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, it is.  I will look at the "verifiable example" page.  Thank you.